# Tiled images in swing

Tags: java, image, swing, tiles

I have task to prepare two windows with swing. One contains grid of squares, with random numbers in them. In second I need to load pieces of tiled image and then show them in the correct order, forming tiled image.

Windows should look like this :

[alt text http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/3129/lab8a.jpg](http://img535.imageshack.us/img535/3129/lab8a.jpg)

Okay so how to bite this? I've used swing only few times to draw some 2d polylines, so basically I just theoretically now what to do.

Ok, so window number 1:
    I start with creating Jframe for the window. Then I do for loop and in it create 16 JLabels with random numbers in them? How to set margins between each tile and the whole window?

Window number 2:
    So I start the same, but instead of loading numbers I add images? Now, how can I load image from file and then set it as background?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the linked image is gone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code lays out the JLabels using the `GridLayout`. The arguments to the `GridLayout` are the following: rows, cols, horizontal gap, vertical gap. In the example below I have 3 pixels wide gap between labels both vertically and horizontally.

To use images instead of numbers, you could pass an `ImageIcon` to the constructor of the JLabel instead of the text.

However, it looks like your doing a game where the user should be able to click on the tiles. This suggests that you perhaps should use buttons instead of labels, but it's up to you :-)

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;


public class FrameTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Frame Test");

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3));

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            JLabel l = new JLabel("" + i, JLabel.CENTER);
            //JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("image_file.png"), JLabel.CENTER);
            l.setBorder(BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED));
            l.setFont(l.getFont().deriveFont(20f));
            panel.add(l);
        }

        f.setContentPane(panel);
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]